# How to recursively change files in directories whose name matches a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, find

I have many directories for different projects. Under some project directories, there are subdirectories named "matlab_programs". In only subdirectories named matlab_programs, I would like to replace the string 'red' with 'blue' in files ending with *.m.

The following perl code will recursively replace the strings in all *.m files, regardless of what subdirectories the files are in.

```
find . -name "*.m" | xargs perl -p -i -e "s/red/blue/g"
```

And to find the full paths of all directories called matlab_programs,

```
find . -type d -name "matlab_programs"
```

How can I combine these so I only replace strings if the files are in a subdirectory called matlab_programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find all directories named `matlab_programs` using

```
find . -type d -name "matlab_programs"
```

and then execute

```
find $f -name "*.m" | xargs perl -p -i -e "s/red/blue/g"
```

on all results `$f`.  Judging by your use of `xargs`, there are no special characters such as spaces in your file names. so the following should work:

```
find `find . -type d -name "matlab_programs"` -name "*.m" |
xargs perl -p -i -e "s/red/blue/g"
```

or

```
find . -type d -name "matlab_programs" |
while read f
do
  find $f -name "*.m" | xargs perl -p -i -e "s/red/blue/g"
done |
xargs perl -p -i -e "s/red/blue/g"
```

Incidentally, I'd use single quotes here; I always use them whenever the quoted string is to be taken literally.

Comment: This worked and was easy for me to understand despite my limited Perl background, so thanks!

Comment: Blank spaces (which were in the project directory names that matlab_programs subdirectories appear under, rather than file names) did cause a problem. But this only happened in a couple of the hundred subdirectories, and when it did happen I understand what was going on because of your comment.

Comment: The examples can be fixed to handle spaces in names, but it is always a hassle. It is better to clean up your file names beforehand if you can.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has the excellent `File::Find` module, that lets you specify a callback to be called on each file.

So you can specified a complex compound criteria, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub find_files {
    next unless m/\.m\z/;    # skip any files that don't end in .m
    if ( $File::Find::dir =~ m/matlab_programs$/ ) {
        print $File::Find::name, " found\n";
    }
}

find( \&find_files, "." );
```

And then you can do whatever you wish with the files you find - like opening/text replacing and closing.

Comment: Use `\z` rather than `$` when matching filenames ... unless you explicitly want `"program.m\n"` to match.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: In which case the pattern should be `/\.m\n?\z/`. Few people -- including Linux users -- are aware that Linux file names may contain control characters except for NUL

Comment: Few people need to. Whilst it is true there can be a load of nastiness embedded in a filename,  we are talking about finding matlab files in a particular directory structure. It isn't unreasonable to assume those particular files don't.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `bash`? The `$(...)` syntax works like backticks (the way both the shell and Perl use them) but they can be nested.

```
perl -pi -e s/red/blue/g $(find $(find . -type d -name matlab_programs) -type f -name \*.m)
```

Many flavors of `find` also support a `-path pattern` test, so you can just combine your filename conditions into that argument

```
perl -pi -e s/red/blue/g $(find . -type f -path \*/matlab_programs/\*.m)
```